# Programmatically change default value of db.model property

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

If a property has a default value like:

```
class myModel(db.Model):
    myProperty = db.SomeProperty(default='Default')
```

Is there a way to programmatically (such that it could be triggered by user interaction) alter the `'Default'` value?

The best way I can think of is more of a hack around it - to have this property refer to something else by default, and then I change the value of what is referred to (changing it then for all entities).

But is there a better way, to more directly change the default?

Comment: Why not just set the `myProperty` property programmatically when creating/updating the entity? If that doesn't work, you could look into `ndb.ComputedProperty` [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed), but you would have to upgrade from `db` to `ndb`.

Comment: @user3058197 Unless I misunderstand you, that would require maintaining a 'defaults' datastore entry, and overloading `put` to set `if not self.myProperty: self.myProperty = defaults.myModel_myProperty` .. which seems kinda hacky.

Comment: I misunderstood your question -- I think you will have to change it for all entities.

Comment: This is a bad idea, you would be setting the default for the myModel class for the instance it is running on.  So if you didn't explicitly set it with every creation of myModel other calls would get the new default value.  (You would be instantiateing a new db.SomeProperty() in the class).

You should use a factory to create instances of myModel and set up the defaults you want there.

Comment: @TimHoffman I don't think I would..? If it was a `db.ReferenceProperty` then I just change the *value* of `db.SomeProperty` in the default instance. Downside is that I have two db reads every time I want to access this property.

Comment: Try, I feel this way leads to all sorts of problems.  Changing the default only changes the value for new entities (created after changing the default).  All earlier entities have the original value.  The "Default" is written to the datastore.  I would revisit your actual use case and requirements.

Comment: No - if it's a reference property, then the default *reference* property is always the same. But the value of whatever property in the *referred* entity can change, and is then changed for all that have the default, applied at whatever time.